# Show file input when click button event on LotusScript?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am working with Lotus Domino. When I read the xml file I want to click on a button and it displays a form to let me select the file:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
 //How to file input form display here
End Sub
```

There's still one more problem.I read the xml file and output data is documents:

```
Dim reader As New XmlNodeReader
Call reader.ReadFile(datas)
documents = reader.getNodeReaders("egov.document ")
Forall document In documents
 //How to display list document for my form
End Forall
```

Please help me in the shortest possible time.Thanks all!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a dialog that allows you to select a file, use the [Prompt](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/it/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_PROMPT_METHOD_7966_ABOUT.html) method of the [NotesUIWorkspace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/it/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESUIWORKSPACE_CLASS.html) class.

The rest of your question requires knowledge of the particular XML schema you are working with.

Comment: I can not find Prompt method of the NotesUIWorkspace.It can not display the input form file that I need

Comment: Hmmm... I thought that NotesUIWorkspace.Prompt included a PROMPT_CHOOSEFILE feature that would be similar to the LOCALBROWSE option of the @Prompt function in formula language, but NotesUIWorkspaceonly includes a PROMPT_CHOOSEDATABASE feature.

Comment: Yeah.Thanks for help! I've found a NotesUIWorkspace.OpenFileDialog method that I need. It works well

Comment: You should actually add that as an answer to your own question!